# How to change local address in fetch API React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I have a local API which is hosted in `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and React server is in `http://127.0.0.1:5500`. I want to design a user interface for the API by a React webpage. But React puts its local address in front of the Get Api like `http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/127.0.0.1:8080/lst/users`. Even if I just put `/lst/users` in the fetch method address and define a proxy `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"` in the app.json, the React will try to get `http://127.0.0.1:5500/lst/users`. How should I fix this.

```
// get all entities - GET
fetch('127.0.0.1:8080/lst/users', {
  "method": "GET",
  mode:'no-cors',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  credentials:'include'

})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
  this.setState({
    friends: response
  })
})
.catch(err => { console.log(err); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the protocol else it will be treated as relative path.

add "http" => `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

E.g.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/lst/users', {
  "method": "GET",
  mode:'no-cors',
  credentials:'include'

})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
  this.setState({
    friends: response
  })
})
.catch(err => { console.log(err); 
});
```